# Ассемблерная вставка, Error: "invalid use of register"

Tags: c, циклы, ассемблер, матрицы

Не работает ассемблерная вставка, хочу посчитать обратную матрицу, используя ассемблер. Но для проверки параллельно считаю на Си для проверки вычислений. Но получаю ошибку  "junk '2' after expression" [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<locale.h>
#include<malloc.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define scanf_s scanf // была ошибка undefined reference to scanf_s


int main()
{


const int n=3;
double det;
//////////////////////
// выделение памяти //
//////////////////////
double **matr; // для матрицы
matr = (double**) malloc(n*sizeof(double*));
 for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
     matr[i] = (double*) malloc(n*sizeof(double));
 if (NULL == matr) {
         printf("Память не выделилась для matr\n");
         exit(1);
    }
 // *для матрцы миноров* //
 double **min; // для матрицы
min = (double**) malloc(n*sizeof(double*));
 for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
     min[i] = (double*) malloc(n*sizeof(double));
 if (NULL == min) {
         printf("Память не выделилась для min\n");
         exit(1);
    }
// *для матрицы алгебраических дополнений* //
double **algdop; // для матрицы
algdop = (double**) malloc(n*sizeof(double*));
 for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
     algdop[i] = (double*) malloc(n*sizeof(double));
 if (NULL == algdop) {
         printf("Память не выделилась для algdop\n");
         exit(1);
    }
// *для транспонированной матрицы * //
double **tmatr; // для матрицы
tmatr = (double**) malloc(n*sizeof(double*));
 for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
     tmatr[i] = (double*) malloc(n*sizeof(double));
 if (NULL == tmatr) {
         printf("Память не выделилась для tmatr\n");
         exit(1);
    }
// *для обратной матрицы * //
double **obr_matr; // для матрицы
obr_matr = (double**) malloc(n*sizeof(double*));
 for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
     obr_matr[i] = (double*) malloc(n*sizeof(double));
 if (NULL == obr_matr) {
         printf("Память не выделилась для obr_matr\n");
         exit(1);
    }
    

 ////////////////////////
 // заполнение матрицы //
 ////////////////////////
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("a[%d][%d] = ", i+1, j+1);
       // scanf_s("%lf", &matr[i][j]);
        if (!scanf("%lf", &matr[i][j])){ fflush(stdin); printf("Ошибка ввода! Нужно писать чиселки\n"); return 0;} 
    }
}
 /////////////////////////////
 // вывод введенной матрицы //
 /////////////////////////////
 printf("Введенная матрица:\n");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  //  проходим по строкам
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { // проходим по столбцам
        printf("%g ", matr[i][j]);
   // printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}


/////////////////////////////
// нахождение определителя //
/////////////////////////////

 det = matr[0][0]*matr[1][1]*matr[2][2] + matr[0][1]*matr[1][2]*matr[2][0]
+ matr[1][0]*matr[2][1]*matr[0][2] - matr[2][0]*matr[1][1]*matr[0][2] -
matr[2][1]*matr[1][2]*matr[0][0] - matr[1][0]*matr[0][1]*matr[2][2];

printf("Определитель  (C) = %lf\n", det);

// асемблерная вставка //
//  6 слагаемых
// проходим по массиву

   
  double *D = &det; // указатель на определитель 
            
    
                                /////////////////////////
                                // нахождение  миноров //
                                /////////////////////////
                                ////////////////////////////
                                //     0        1      2  //   
                                //0 - [0][0] [0][1] [0][2]//
                                //1 - [1][0] [1][1] [1][2]//
                                //2 - [2][0] [2][1] [2][2]//
                                ////////////////////////////
        min[0][0]= matr[1][1] * matr[2][2] - matr[2][1] * matr[1][2];
        min[0][1]= matr[1][0] * matr[2][2] - matr[1][2] * matr[2][0];
        min[0][2]= matr[1][0] * matr[2][1] - matr[2][0] * matr[1][1];
        min[1][0]= matr[0][1] * matr[2][2] - matr[2][1] * matr[0][2];
        min[1][1]= matr[0][0] * matr[2][2] - matr[2][0] * matr[0][2];
        min[1][2]= matr[0][0] * matr[2][1] - matr[2][0] * matr[0][1];
        min[2][0]= matr[0][1] * matr[1][2] - matr[1][1] * matr[0][2];
        min[2][1]= matr[0][0] * matr[1][2] - matr[1][0] * matr[0][2];
        min[2][2]= matr[0][0] * matr[1][1] - matr[1][0] * matr[0][1];
        
      //  printf("Минор первого элемента матрицы = %lf\n", min[0][0]); // проверял правильность расчетов
      //  printf("Минор второго элемента матрицы = %lf\n", min[0][1]); // 
        
// *матрица алгебраических дополнений* //
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            int k; // степень
            k=i+j;
            algdop[i][j]= pow(-1.0, k) *  min[i][j]; // матрица алгелраических дополнений
    }
}
// *вывод матрицы алгебраических дополнений* //
 printf("Матрица алгебраических дополнений:\n");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  //  проходим по строкам
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { // проходим по столбцам
        printf("%g ", algdop[i][j]);
   // printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
// *Транспонируем матрицу* //
        
           for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)   
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        tmatr[j][i] = algdop[i][j];
        
// *вывод транспонированной матрицы* //
 printf("Транспонированная матрица :\n");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  //  проходим по строкам
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { // проходим по столбцам
        printf("%g ", tmatr[i][j]);
   // printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}


 // *вывод обратной матрицы до заполнения* //
 printf("Обратная матрица до заполнения :\n");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  //  проходим по строкам
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { // проходим по столбцам
        printf("%g ", obr_matr[i][j]);
   // printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

 ///////////////////////////////////////////
 // и наконец-то обратная матрицааааааааа //
 ///////////////////////////////////////////

       
           for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)   
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        obr_matr[i][j] = tmatr[i][j] / det;
        
        
// *вывод обратной матрицы (С)* //
 printf("Обратная матрица (C) :\n");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  //  проходим по строкам
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { // проходим по столбцам
        printf("%g ", obr_matr[i][j]);
   // printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
                 // асемблерная вставка //
asm
(
      ".intel_syntax noprefix\n" /*Синтаксис Intel, допускается опускать % перед именами регистров*/
      "\n\tmov rbx, %0"
      "\n\tmovss xmm0, [%1]" // в регистр xmm0 заночим определитель
      "\n\tmov rcx, 0"  // присваем начальное значение для счетчика по i (строкам)
     
      "\n\tloop1:"       // переход на след строчку
      "\n\tmov rdx, 0"  // присваем начальное значение для счетчика j //  находится в теле loop1, т к необходимо каждую строку проходить с нулевого элемента
      "\n\tinc rcx"     // увеличиваем счетчик (i) на 1
      "\n\tloop2:"      // переход к след эдементу в строчке
      "\n\tinc rdx"     // увеличиваем счетчик по элементам в строке (j)
      "\n\tmov rax, [rbx+8*rcx]"
      "\n\tlea r8, [rax+8*rdx]"
      "\n\tmovss xmm1, [r8]" // в xmm1 заносим значение элемента массива
      // тело цикла
      "\n\tdivss xmm1, xmm0"  // делим эллемент массива на определитель 

      "\n\tcmp rdx 2 "   // сравниваем счетчик по элементам строки (j) c 2
      "\n\tje loop1"     // и если он равен, переходим к loop1 т е след строке 
      "\n\tcmp rcx 2 "   // сравниваем счетчик строк (i) с 2
      "\n\tje loop3"     // и если истинно, переходим к loop3 т е завершаем работу
      "\n\tjmp loop2"    // если дошло до этой строки, то переходим к след элементу
      "\n\tloop3:"       // метка для завершения работы
    :  /*выходные операнды отсутствуют*/
    : "r"(tmatr), "r"(D) /*входные операторы*/
    : "%rax", "%rcx", "%xmm0", "%xmm1" ,  "memory", "cc" /*разрушаемые регистры (в формате %имя или memory --- для указания обизменении содержимого памяти, cc --- для указания на изменение регистра флагов) */
 );
   // *вывод обратной матрицы (Asm)* // выводится tmatr  так как мы изменяем значения в памяти
    printf("Обратная матрица (Asm) :\n");
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {  //  проходим по строкам
       for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { // проходим по столбцам
           printf("%g ", tmatr[i][j]);
      // printf("\n");
       }
       printf("\n");
   }
    
 /////////////////////////
 // освобождение памяти //
 /////////////////////////
  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
      free (matr[i]);
      free (matr);          
}
// *для матрицы миноров* //
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
      free (min[i]);
      free (min);          
}
// *для матрицы алгебраических дополнений* //
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
      free (algdop[i]);
      free (algdop);          
}
 // *для транспонированной матрицы * //
  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
      free (tmatr[i]);
      free (tmatr);          
}
// *для обратной матрицы * //
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) {
      free (obr_matr[i]);
      free (obr_matr);          
}

return 0;        
}
```

Comment: Кроме отсутствия запятых, в команде `jе loop3` русская буква `е`.

Answer (score 0):

Нет запятой mov rax [rbx+8*rcx] и т.д

Comment: Спасибо)) исправил, но Junk остался

Comment: А у меня встречный вопрос, почему во второй строке ассемблерной вставки "\n\tmov rbx, %0" ты поставил запятую?